# how can delete folders in c sharp

Tags: c#, directory, delete-file

I have some folders and these folders have some text files and i need delete these files but i catch an error with my code!

```
                    var dateFolder = Directory.GetDirectories(@"data\stdate").Select(Path.GetDirectoryName).ToArray();
                    foreach (var dateFile in dateFolder)
                    {
                        var stDates =
                            Directory.GetFiles(@"data\stdate\" + dateFile + "date").Select(Path.GetFileName).ToArray();

                        foreach (var date in stDates)
                        {
                            File.Delete(@"data\stdate\" + dateFile + "date\\" + date);
                        }
                        Directory.Delete(@"data\stdate\" + dateFile + "date");
                    }
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\asus\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\SchoolPresent\SchoolPresent\bin\Debug\data\stdate\data\stdatedate'.

Comment: That answers your question.. That path does not exist.

Comment: i know , but i don't know what is wrong in my codes!?

Comment: And what do you expect to get? What foldet to get deleted?

Comment: i need fined --> data\stdate\FolderName but variable dateFile in first foreach have this value : data\stdate not data\stdate\FolderName1

Comment: What is the path you want to delete?
Where are you running you application from? (Given that you are using relative paths, I imagine this is your problem!)

Comment: i need delete all folders in stdate folder for example --> data \ stdate \ Folder1 -- or data \ stdate \ Folder2 or...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
Directory.Delete("Path", true); //true: It will delete directory by given path, also folders and files in it.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    System.IO.DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"data\stdate");

         //This for delete all file in "data\stdate"
        foreach (FileInfo file in di.GetFiles())
        {
            file.Delete();
        }
        //***************************For delete file in folder

        //This for delete all Subfolder and his files in "data\stdate"
        foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in di.GetDirectories())
        {
            dir.Delete(true);
        }
        //*************************
        //This for delete the parent folder "stdate"
        di.Delete();
```

Comment: i don't know what is my folder name! and i most be fined folders and delete that files but your codes first goes to delete file in folder!

Comment: Yes he delete the files first and then the folders and subfolders.you should just replace "YourPath" by  @"data\stdate"

Comment: path date\stdate just have some folders not files! but that folders have files

Answer (score 0):

i delete my original folder and i create it again!

```
 if (!isDateEmpty)
                {
                    Directory.Delete(@"data\stdate", true);
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(@"data\stdate");
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use system environment variables, see here:

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable

The reason being, like you found out: sometimes the executable is not running in the directory you expected when you compiled the program.

EX:

```
    String query = "%SystemDrive%";
    str = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(query);

    Delete(str, true);
```

That way it guarantees a predictable path as opposed to a relative one.